# GenericDao: @Transactional not working.. again

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Im trying to make webservice based on GenericDao. I have Person Entity and im trying to make dao for that Entity exteded by GenericDao. But `@Transactional` annotation does not open transaction: `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() = false`

I can't find where i missed `@Transactional`. I have tried to add `@Transactional` almost everywhere. It feels like the annotations does not inherit from GenericDao..

**spring-config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
      xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

      <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

      <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/test" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="postgress" />
      </bean>

      <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
        <value>org.entity.nci.person.Person</value>
        </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
          <props>
            <prop 
             key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

          </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.byteslounge.spring.tx.model" />
      </bean>

      <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
      </bean>
      <tx:advice id="transactionAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">  
      <tx:attributes>    
        <tx:method name="*"/>
      </tx:attributes>
      </tx:advice>

    </beans>
```

**GenericDao.java**

```
package org.dao.nci.person;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public interface GenericDao<E,K> {
    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    public String add(List<E> entities) ;
    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    public String saveOrUpdate(E entity) ;
    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    public String update(E entity, String whereClause) ;
    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    public String remove(E entity);
    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    public E find(K key);
    @WebMethod(exclude = true)
    public List<E> get(String whereClause) ;
}
```

**GenericDaoImpl.java**

```
package org.dao.nci.person;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Repository

public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<E, K extends Serializable> 
        implements GenericDao<E, K> {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Class<? extends E> daoType;

    public GenericDaoImpl() {
        Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
        daoType = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    protected Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String add(List<E> entities) {
        for(Object entity : entities){
            currentSession().save(entity);
        }
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String saveOrUpdate(E entity) {
        currentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String update(E entity, String whereClause) {
        currentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public  String remove(E entity) {
        currentSession().delete(entity);
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public E find(K key) {
        Session session = currentSession();

        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        transaction.commit();

        //session.close();
        return (E) session.get(daoType, key);
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<E> get(String filter) {
        List<E> records =  currentSession().createCriteria(daoType).list();
        return records;
    }
}
```

**PersonDao.java**

```
package org.dao.nci.person;

import java.util.List;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.entity.nci.person.Person;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@WebService
@XmlRootElement(name = "ComplexService")
@Transactional
public interface PersonDao extends GenericDao<Person, String>{



    @WebMethod(operationName = "selectPerson")
    @WebResult(name="row")
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Person> get(@WebParam(name="filter") String whereClause);
    @WebMethod(operationName = "insertPerson")
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String add(@WebParam(name="row") List<Person> persons);

}
```

**PersonDaoImpl.java**

```
package org.dao.nci.person;

import java.util.List;

import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.entity.nci.person.Person;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;



@WebService(endpointInterface = "example.catalog.ProductCatalogService",
serviceName = "ProductCatalogService")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class PersonDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Person, String> 
                        implements PersonDao {





    }
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried both advices:

Overrided methods in *PersonDaoImpl.java* like this:

```
package org.dao.nci.person;

import java.util.List;

import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.entity.nci.person.Person;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;



@WebService(endpointInterface = "example.catalog.ProductCatalogService",
serviceName = "ProductCatalogService")
public class PersonDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Person, String> 
                    implements PersonDao {

@Override
@Transactional
public String add(List<Person> entities){
    return super.add(entities);
}




}
```

And i tried to set proxy-target-class="false"

Both did not help.. Method completes without any errors but not commited. `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` is still False.

Comment: It's unclear to me why you'd want to annotate the interface.  Also, there's no actual implementation or any actual method to annotate in your impl from what I can see.

Comment: I was just trying to annotate everything after hours of trying. Its true where is no need @Transactional in interface. About implementation you mean PersonDaoImpl.java? I just want to extend it from GenericDaoImpl.java without adding any new methods. I was trying to Override it with Transactional annotation but it did not work.

Comment: How is your PersonDaoImpl constructed, by Spring?  I don't see it in your application context but it may be you only posted part.

Answer (score -1):

From the [Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations):

> Spring recommends that you only annotate concrete classes (and methods
>   of concrete classes) with the @Transactional annotation, as opposed to
>   annotating interfaces. You certainly can place the @Transactional
>   annotation on an interface (or an interface method), but this works
>   only as you would expect it to if you are using interface-based
>   proxies. The fact that Java annotations are not inherited from
>   interfaces means that if you are using class-based proxies
>   (proxy-target-class="true") or the weaving-based aspect
>   (mode="aspectj"), then the transaction settings are not recognized by
>   the proxying and weaving infrastructure, and the object will not be
>   wrapped in a transactional proxy, which would be decidedly bad.

I believe class-based proxies is the default so you will either need to change that or come up with a new way of solving your problem.

Comment: Also, as an aside, the DAO is not usually the best place to place transactions (too close to the operation) so I don't know if this is a very typical use case.

Comment: You mean annotations must be placed in PersonDaoImpl.java?

Comment: Either that, or change the proxy mode to interface based proxies.